# Create or Alter PostgreSQL Table to ensure Django Models match

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I ran into an annoying issue today during the development of a Django project where I was attempting to move between a testing database and a development database, and I cannot seem to figure out a solid way to go about fixing issues with migrations.

Let's call my 'test' DB: **testDB** and my 'dev' DB: **devDB**

I was accessing **testDB** as usual through Django settings.py and I made migrations adding the **clientID** field you see in the code below.

Then, I decided to swap to **devDB** in my Django's settings.py to run **python manage.py migrate**, and my **clientID** field is not added to the new DB. When I run **python manage.py makemigrations** I get, as expected, "no changes detected".

Just so this is noted, I am using the django-reset-migrations package from PyPi after I make migrations so the migrations folder does not get complicated and everything is stored in a single 0001_initial.py migrations file.

I am not seeing a better way to handle this issue than by writing my own script that ensures all Model tables exist in whatever DB I am connected to, and that all Model fields are located in each table, else the table is altered and the appropriate columns are added, which brings me to my question...

If I use: **python manage.py sqlmigrate objects 0001** (which is my 0001_initial.py file), I am presented with the creation code below:

```
CREATE TABLE "objects_users" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    "clientID" integer NOT NULL, 
    "email" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "first_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "last_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "phone" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "password" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "type" varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    "date_created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, 
    "active" varchar(100) NOT NULL);
```

How do I take this creation statement and loop the included fields to ensure that they are available in the DB I am connected to (using alter statements I am assuming would be the best way)?

**Big Note**

I have only been working with Django for a few months, but I do recall the documentation of Django saying it is normally a best idea to add the attriubute **null=true** to added **Model.fields** so they are simply added to the database automatically when migrations occur. I am not sure if this is an issue in my instance, I am just trying to find a solution that automatically ensures no matter what database I am connected to, I am fully synced and there are no SQL errors stating a field does not exist, even when I run migrations.

So far I have been able to fix my issues my clearing out whatever Database I am connected to and then running **python manage.py migrate** based on the initial migrations file, but this is not a valid solution for a production instance where I am unable to reset everything.

**I need ideas, I think the alter table statement based on the string I get from `python manage.py sqlmigrate objects 0001` is best so far, but I am open to anything that will fix my issue so I do not have to worry about this anymore.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Just so this is noted, I am using the django-reset-migrations package from PyPi after I make migrations so the migrations folder does not get complicated and everything is stored in a single 0001_initial.py migrations file.***

The solution to your problem is simple: stop doing this.

Resetting migration files in that way is an advanced, potentially dangerous technique. It's never required, but might be helpful in some circumstances. The migrations folder "getting complicated" is not a real problem that needs to be solved, especially for a beginning project.

What makes it dangerous is that, by design, it's erasing the history of changes made to your models and database. So if you run it when a database is not fully updated—as you've apparently done—you've deleted the information necessary to do so. (Specifically, when you reset the migrations before migrating your dev database you deleted the file that specifies how to add the new column.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'm inclined to mark this as correct, but let me test not reseting migrations and moving database connections today to see if I run into issues. Just so I am clear, are you saying that if I leave the migrations files alone (i.e. Not resetting them), I'll be able to switch Databases, run **manage.py migrate** and it will sync up correctly whether the tables in the new DB exist or not? - Essentially meaning not using **django-reset-migrations** is the best option.

Comment: @ViaTech: Yes. Indeed, that is the main purpose of having migrations in the first place. Note that this suggestion isn't going to fix your existing database problem. You indicated that you were willing to start from scratch, so do that and going forward you won't have this problem.

Comment: Yes, I have gathered this will fix my issues as long as I keep the migrations in tact. Wonderful, thanks! Can you describe a "good situation" to reset migrations so I know for future reference?

Comment: @ViaTech: The main downside to having a huge number of migrations is that it can slow down tests, since the test database is constructed from scratch each time (unless you use `--keepdb`). That's a commonly cited motivation. Note that Django has a built-in, safer, less comprehensive version of this [migration squashing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations).

Comment: great I will look into Django's migration squashing when I get the chance later today, thanks!